# escaping PHP array delimiter out of string

Tags: php

I'm grabbing data out of an API, and every once in a while, a value comes back in one of the fields I'm capturing that has a comma in it, which is causing my results to be offset by 1 each time it happens.

after I've gotten the results from the API, I put it into `$answerSearch`, then I `json_decode` it.

```
$json = json_decode($answerSearch, true);
foreach ($json['Result']['a']['b'] as $i) {

  $y = "{$i['number']},{$i['Type']},{$i['c']},{$i['d']},{$i['e']}"; 
  $x = explode("," , $y);
  array_push($output, $x);
}
```

One of these `{$i['number']}` values may be `"1234,123"`, and because I use comma as a delimiter, it's causing the entire array to screw up.

How do I tell PHP that the `,` in the middle of this string is part of the string and not a delimeter?

## Update

I can't just change `$x = explode("," , $y);` to use another delimiter because `,`, `/`, `;`, etc are all used in the actual strings that are being returned, I was just using `,` as an example.

Comment: why not just change your delimiter to something the api wont return ~^ ?

Comment: That code is utterly pointless. `$i` is already an array, so why convert that array to a string, just to explode it back to an array? If you're doing this to copy only the keys you want, there's better ways of doing this...

Comment: actully skip y and x and write directly to an array

Comment: @MarcB, it's not pointless, it does exactly what I want it to.  The original array that comes over is massive, and I'm looking to just take 5 fields out of it (`number, type, c, d, and e)`, and this code does that.

Comment: `$output[]=array({$i['number']},{$i['Type']},{$i['c']},{$i['d']},{$i['e']});` ?

Comment: Have you seen array_map? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: "*How do I tell PHP that the , in the middle of this string is part of the string and not a delimeter?*" It's hard to say without knowing *exactly* what data you get, but if one comma is required and one not, use regex to identify one of the commas. "eg" Remove commas which are not next to a number (preg_replace/whatever). But this depends on how the data is formatted. A comma delimiter when you expect comma in the string is not an ideal approach. Can't you set another delimiter? Or pass the data from the API in a more useful structure - ie already in an array?

Comment: @Dagon, yeah, that looks like it would work.  Let me give it a shot.

Comment: @James, that's a good point, and I think the way I was going about this was not very efficient in the first place.  If I don't bother splitting it and rejoining it in the first place I don't have to worry about any of this.

Comment: Well, if there's a reason to split it pre API do so - don't neglect requirements just to fix an issue elsewhere. But otherwise, yeah pass it in whatever manner is useful based on who/what is going to be using it at the other side.

Comment: @JohnWu: yes, it is pointless: `$output[] = array($i['number'], $i['type'], etc...)`. Absolutely **NO** string manipulation required.

Comment: @MarcB, I guess it's a question of semantics then.  It's not pointless in my opinion because the code does what I wrote it to do.  Whether or not it's the most efficient way of doing it or not, or whether certain errors are caused by its implementation, you can't say it's pointless when it works.  Saying it's `inefficient` is a perfect word, but `pointless` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no for the conversion from array to string back to an array, to add the selected values to the $output array use:

```
$output[]=array({$i['number']},{$i['Type']},{$i['c']},{$i['d']},{$i['e']});
```